# rEFInd Boot Manager not loading (Arch Linux installation)

Tags: arch-linux, refind

I'm trying to install rEFInd as my Arch Linux bootloader, but I can't get the boot manager to start.

I'm installing it from an Arch Linux live installation, booted from USB installation media. I've installed the `refind` package from pacman. I tried using the installer command `refind-install --usedefault /dev/sdb2 --alldrivers`, but that wasn't working, so I deleted everything and tried a [manual installation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/REFInd#Manual_installation).

Here's what my EFI directory looks like:

```
/boot/EFI/refind
            |___drivers_x64
            |    |___ext4_x64.efi
            |___refind.conf
            |___refind_x64.efi
```

Here's the output of `efibootmgr`:

```
BootCurrent: 0005
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0004,0005,0006,0007
Boot0000* rEFInd Boot Manager
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0005* UEFI: Generic Flash Disk 8.07
Boot0006* UEFI: Generic Flash Disk 8.07, Partition 2
Boot0007* UEFI: Samsung SSD 860 EVO M.2 1TB, Partition 2
```

Relevant parts of `efibootmgr -v` (with Windows Boot Manager for comparison):

```
BootOrder: 0000,0004,0005,0006,0007
Boot0000* rEFInd Boot Manager    HD(2,GPT,[uuid],0x109000,0x200000)/File(\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi)
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager   HD(2,GPT,[uuid],0x109000,0x200000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.....
```

You can see that rEFInd Boot Manager has the highest priority in the BootOrder, but when I try to boot using that, it opens Dell SupportAssist, meaning it's not loading. Secure Boot is disabled.

I may have messed up my rEFInd configuration for Arch Linux, but the issue is that rEFInd isn't loading at all. Does anybody know what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I got it working. What I ended up doing was:

1. Burn the rEFInd **CD** image to a USB drive (https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html). While in `arch-chroot`, I used used `wget` and then the command `dd if=image.iso of=/dev/sdd`.
2. Boot into that; it loaded fine
3. Select the installation option from the rEFInd menu

And now it works! Still don't know why it wasn't working before, but the entries in `efibootmgr -v` are a little different (the working one has some stuff about PciRoot/Pci/Sata/HD instead of just HD).